# Crear nueva matriz a partir de una ya obtenida, C++

Tags: c++, archivo, matriz

Me encontraba programando en C++ un algoritmo que tengo que realizar y durante el proceso me ha surgido un problema el cual no sé como resolver ya que aun soy un novato en esto de C++.
Mi problema es el siguiente. Durante la creación del algoritmo, he obtenido una matriz de la siguiente forma:

```
  1   4   5   6  2  3  7  8
  6  10  10  11 18 12  5  7 
-29 -13 -11 -11  5  7 33 38
```

El caso es que yo quiero que mi algoritmo sea capaz, a partir de esta matriz obtenida, de crearme una matriz donde en este caso solo tendría las últimas cuatro columnas. Es decir, desde que los elementos de la tercera fila son positivos. De manera que la matriz2 (por llamarla de alguna manera) que el programa me tendría que dar sería esta:

```
2   3  7  8
18 12  5  7 
5   7 33 38
```

A continuación os adjunto mi programa:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> //para salida y entrada de datos por consola
#include <fstream>   //para salida y entrada de datos del fichero
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>


using namespace std;



bool existeEnVector(vector<int> v, int busqueda) {
    return find(v.begin(), v.end(), busqueda) != v.end();
}


int main(void)
{
    int filas, columnas;
//En primer lugar, leo la matriz desde un fichero de txt
    const char* nombre_fichero1 = "pruebadinamica.txt"; //nombre del fichero de la matriz
    ifstream fichero1 (nombre_fichero1);
    fichero1>>filas;
    fichero1>>columnas;

    float** matriz;
    matriz = new float*[filas];
    for (int i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        matriz[i]=new float[columnas];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<columnas; j++)
        {
            fichero1>>matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    fichero1.close();

//Ordeno la matriz en función a mi tercera fila
    float aux, auxi, auxil;
    int pos;

    for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++){

        pos=j;
        aux=matriz[0][j];
        auxi=matriz[1][j];
        auxil=matriz[2][j];
        while((pos>0)&&(matriz[2][pos-1]>auxil)){
            matriz[0][pos]=matriz[0][pos-1];
            matriz[1][pos]=matriz[1][pos-1];
            matriz[2][pos]=matriz[2][pos-1];
            pos--;
        }
        matriz[0][pos]=aux;
        matriz[1][pos]=auxi;
        matriz[2][pos]=auxil;

    }
    int suma;
    suma=0;
    vector<int> s1,s2;
    for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++){
        if(matriz[2][j]<=matriz[2][j+1] && matriz[1][j]<=matriz[1][j+1]){
            s1.insert(s1.end(),matriz[0][j]);
            suma=suma+matriz[1][j];
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
        if(matriz[2][j]<=matriz[2][j+1] && matriz[1][j]<=matriz[1][j+1] && existeEnVector(s1, matriz[0][j-1])){
            s1.insert(s1.end(),matriz[0][j]);
            suma=suma+matriz[1][j];
        }
    }
     for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
        matriz[2][j]=matriz[2][j]-suma;
    }

//AQUÍ SERÍA DONDE QUIERO CREAR LA MATRIZ NUEVA A PARTIR DE LO OBTENIDO
    for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
    {
        delete[] matriz[i];
    }
    delete[] matriz;

        system("PAUSE"); //para que no se cierre al terminar el programa
        return 0; //Debe devolver algo el main, lo que e de la gana
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: A partir del código que ya tengo, ¿Qué debo añadir para que a partir de la matriz que tengo me cree una matriz en la cual solo estén las columnas cuya tercera fila (de la matriz inicial) sean números positivos?

Comment: A partir del código que tienes: Nada. Tu código es complicado de más, excesivo, ineficiente, propenso a errores y difícil de leer, depurar y entender. Te aconsejaría empezar de nuevo usando `std::vector` en lugar de formaciones.